# Принять и обработать открытый файл в Android Activity

Tags: java, android

Нужно реализовать принятие файла и его содержимого, когда он открывается из другого приложения, как показано на скриншоте:[image: Как можно заметить, моё приложение есть в списке инструментов]

Как видно, моё приложение есть в списке "Открыть с помощью"

Проблема в реализации обработки полученного файла.
Что я должен прописать в Activity.java, чтобы он понимал, что открыт определенный файл?

И как перезаписать содержимое файла после редактирования?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: вот например как можно получать данные в вашем приложении - https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Comment: Это почти то, что нужно. getIntent() получает файл, но строчка String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT); выдает пустой String

Comment: посмотрите под отладкой например какие вообще вам приходят строки, что присылает intent, может у вас переменная не так называется

Comment: Я попробовал вывести Intent вместо sharedText. Вот, что получил: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Файл.txt typ=text/plain flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.rianoks.editor/.Editor (has extras) }

Comment: а метод getData().toString() вывел путь к файлу без кодировки UTF-8

Comment: Может все зависит от имени класса?

Comment: ну вам очевидно нужен dat, но не уверен что он будет всегда и везде одинаковым, не думаю что это зависит от имени класса, вы получаете данные в активности, соответственно активность всегда работает одинаково с любым именем

Comment: Вообщем, целый день над этим промучался.. Решил одтолкнуться от того, что имею.. а именно через getData().toString() можно получить путь к файлу и получить содержимое через BufferedReader. Отладчик сразу дал понять, что проблема в знаменитом Android 11, где доступ к файловой системе запрещен: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/file.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)  И что  бы я не делал, даже WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE не помогает... есть идеи?

Comment: Все! Решение нашлось. В манифесте в тег application нужно добавить атрибут android:requestLegacyExternalStorage со значением true и в настройках приложения выдать разрешение на файлы и медиаконтент. Но это же так неудобно....